# Java unbounded wildcard misunderstanding

Tags: java, generics, unbounded-wildcard

Let’s say I define a collection of parametrized types like this:

```
Deque<Node<Integer>> nodes = new LinkedList<>();

nodes.add(new Node(5));
```

Why is it an error to pass that reference to a method with an unbounded wildcard in the signature like this:

```
static void printNodes(Collection<Node<?>> nodes) {...}
```

Comment: You should also mention the error.

Comment: Because generics are invariant, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265 You'd need to change the parameter type to `Collection<? extends Node<?>>`

Comment: You could add a `Node<String>` to a `Collection<Node<?>>`, so a `Collection<Node<Integer>>` is not a `Collection<Node<?>>`.